# I dry ran several times but couldn't find where is the mistake. I am providing my code, can anyone please find out the mistake?

Tags: c

**Link** : https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA01/problems/LAPIN

**Program description** :
Lapindrome is defined as a string which when split in the middle, gives two halves having the same characters and same frequency of each character. If there are odd number of characters in the string, we ignore the middle character and check for lapindrome. For example gaga is a lapindrome, since the two halves ga and ga have the same characters with same frequency. Also, abccab, rotor and xyzxy are a few examples of lapindromes. Note that abbaab is NOT a lapindrome. The two halves contain the same characters but their frequencies do not match.
Your task is simple. Given a string, you need to tell if it is a lapindrome.

**My code :**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main(){
    
    int i,t,len,j,k,arr_indx,check = 0;
    char s[1000],left[500],right[500];
        
        //s[] = input string
        //left[] = left side of the string after division        
        //right[] = right side of the string after division
        //len = length of the input string
        //arr_index = It is the array index 
  
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i = 1;i <= t;i++)
    {
        

        scanf("%s",&s);
        len = strlen(s);
        
        
        //if even length

        if(len % 2 == 0)
        {
            for(j = 0;j < len/2;j++)
                left[j] = s[j];
            left[j] = '\0';
            
            for(k = len/2,arr_indx = 0;k < len;k++,arr_indx++)
                right[arr_indx] = s[k];
            right[arr_indx] = '\0';
        }
        
        //if odd length

        else
        {
            for(j = 0;j < len/2;j++)
                left[j] = s[j];
            left[j] = '\0';
            
            for(k = ((len/2)+1),arr_indx = 0;k < len;k++,arr_indx++)
                right[arr_indx] = s[k];
            right[arr_indx] = '\0';
        }
        
        //Checking

        for(k = 0;k < strlen(left);k++)
            for(j = 0;j < strlen(right);j++)
                if(left[k] == right[j])
                   check++;     

        if(check == strlen(left)) //printing
        printf("YES\n");
        else
        printf("NO\n");
        check = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide input, expected output and actual output. 
Currently we can't guess what is wrong with your code, unless we spend more time reading and testing it than any of  us have.

Comment: Lets's imagine the string `aaaaaa`, it's a lapindrome for sure. How much is `check` going to be? Expecting to get 3(why ?), actual result: 9. Hmm, that's not quite right. Your checking logic is not correct.

Comment: The array sizes for the arrays `s`, `left`, `right` must have been 1001, 501, 501, respectively, to be able to store the null character (`\0`). And, the overall logic is not correct. Even if it were correct, the algorithm would be very inefficient (read slow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you implemented is both incorrect and very slow (even if it was correct). Since the input characters are limited to a..z, you could implement a fast  algorithm by comparing the frequencies of letters in the left and right portions of the input text. An example implementation is below. The code assumes that the character codes of a..z are contiguous, which isn't guaranteed by the C standard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NLETTERS ('z' - 'a' + 1)

int main(void)
{
    int T;
    
    scanf("%d ", &T);
    while (--T >= 0) {
        char buf[1002];
        int lfreq[NLETTERS] = {0}, rfreq[NLETTERS] = {0}, yes = 1;
        fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
        for (int i = 0, j = strcspn(buf, "\n") - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
            ++lfreq[buf[i] - 'a'];
            ++rfreq[buf[j] - 'a'];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NLETTERS; ++i) {
            if (lfreq[i] != rfreq[i]) {
                yes = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        puts(yes ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
    return 0;
}
```